# Implement my own Array Method Help Java

Tags: java, inventory

How would I implement my own method on an element of my own array?

for example, im trying to make a inventory system that if      (INVENTORY[X].isValidID() == TRUE)

Then it returns true,

how would i do that?

```
public void addInv(int ITEM_ID) {
    for(int x = 0; x < MAX_STORAGE; x++) {
        if(INVENTORY[x].isValidID() == true ) {

        }
    }
}

public static boolean isValidID(int X) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely looking for something like this.

```
 public void addInv(int ITEM_ID) {
    for(int x = 0; x < MAX_STORAGE; x++) {
       if(isValidID(INVENTORY[x])) {

      }
    }
}

public static boolean isValidID(int X) {
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: `public static boolean isValidID(int X)` will only work if `INVENTORY` is an array of `int` values. The type of the parameter `X` should match the type of the array.

Comment: @jalv1039 Yeah. I figured the op had that figured out somewhere in their code. Considering there was no other reference made to the Inventory array it had to be declared elsewhere where I couldn't see and therefore didn't care about.